# PM2 data collecting agent takes too much network bandwidth

Tags: node.js, pm2

Recently we found PM2 km agent keeps uploading data very frequently, and the process takes too much network bandwidth.

Is there anyone has any idea about that? 
Is there any impact if we kill the "KM agent" process manually, and let PM2 run without that process?

[The network status about PM2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uvqf.jpg)

[The corresponding process information:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeLvO.jpg)

Part of our agent.log under /xxx/.pm2 directory:

```
2017-07-26 13:25:20: [WARN] Time to send data over TCP took 10.737seconds!
2017-07-26 13:25:20: [WARN] Time to send data over TCP took 9.737seconds!
2017-07-26 13:25:20: [WARN] Time to send data over TCP took 8.737seconds!
2017-07-26 13:25:20: [WARN] Time to send data over TCP took 7.733seconds!
2017-07-26 13:25:20: [WARN] Time to send data over TCP took 6.731seconds!
2017-07-26 13:25:20: [WARN] Time to send data over TCP took 5.73seconds!
2017-07-26 13:25:20: [WARN] Time to send data over TCP took 4.732seconds!
2017-07-26 13:25:25: [WARN] Time to send data over TCP took 8.544seconds!
2017-07-26 13:25:25: [WARN] Time to send data over TCP took 7.544seconds!
2017-07-26 13:25:25: [WARN] Time to send data over TCP took 6.543seconds!
2017-07-26 13:25:25: [WARN] Time to send data over TCP took 5.543seconds!
```